# How to update struct schema in a Spark sql table

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

My data lake has a spark-sql table (`Spark 3.4.0`) in `Delta` format.

The table has a struct column and now I need to add a new field `address` to that struct column.

What I have tried is:

```
drop table if exists temp.test_struct ;
create table if not exists temp.test_struct (
  cola int,
  colb struct<name:STRING, age:int>
)
```

Now alter the column:

```
ALTER TABLE temp.test_struct 
CHANGE COLUMN colb colb struct<name:STRING, age:int, address:STRING>
```

However, I get the error message:

```
AnalysisException: Cannot update hive_metastore.temp.test_struct field colb type: update a struct by updating its fields
```

Detailed error is shown at the end of this page.

Why is that happen and how to address the issue?

Any help is appreciated.

---

Detailed error info:

```
Error in SQL statement: AnalysisException: Cannot update hive_metastore.temp.test_struct field colb type: update a struct by updating its fields.; line 1 pos 0;
AlterColumn resolvedfieldname(StructField(colb,MapType(StringType,StringType,true),true)), StructType(StructField(name,StringType,true),StructField(age,IntegerType,true),StructField(address,StringType,true))
+- ResolvedTable com.databricks.sql.managedcatalog.UnityCatalogV2Proxy@36a5c0b0, temp.test_struct, DeltaTableV2(org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession@234aab1e,s3://xxx/temp/test_struct,Some(CatalogTable(
Catalog: hive_metastore
Database: temp
Table: test_struct
Owner: root
Created Time: Tue Sep 19 07:17:23 UTC 2023
Last Access: UNKNOWN
Created By: Spark 3.4.0
Type: MANAGED
Provider: delta
Table Properties: [delta.lastCommitTimestamp=1695107842000, delta.lastUpdateVersion=0, delta.minReaderVersion=1, delta.minWriterVersion=2]
Location:.....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `ADD COLUMNS`:

```sql
ALTER TABLE temp.test_struct ADD COLUMNS (colb.address STRING)
```

More info [here](https://docs.databricks.com/en/delta/update-schema.html#explicitly-update-schema-to-add-columns).

Comment: Big surprise! I've learnt sth!